# q question regarding the numerical zero finding of Riemann zeta function and actual proof of Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: riemann-zeta

(1)Suppose that people verified in 2004, that all zeros of $\zeta(\sigma+i t)$ with $0<t<T<=10^{22},0<\sigma<1$ are on the critical line ($\sigma=1/2$).

(2)Suppose Bob proved  in 2010 that for $t>=10^{2000}$, all the zeros of $\zeta(\sigma+i t)$ are on the critical line.

(3)Suppose that Alice verified in 2020 that for $10^{22}<=t<=10^{2000}$, all the zeros of $\zeta(\sigma+i t)$ are on the critical line.

Question:
Who is considered to have proved the Riemann Hypothesis?
    (i) Bob
    (ii) Alice
    (iii) Bob and Alice

Comment: [Neither](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation). ;-$)$

Comment: @Lucian Thanks for the reply! So numerical solutions plus symbolic proof are not considered as true proof?

Comment: *The name of Pell's equation arose from Leonhard Euler's mistakenly attributing its study to John Pell. Euler was aware of the work of Lord Brouncker, the first European mathematician to find a general solution of the equation, but apparently confused Brouncker with Pell*. :-$)$